# Get a list of videos

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Has anyone figured out how to get a list of videos in Windows Phone? When trying to access them through Xna.Framework.Media object but it only seems to give access to SongCollection, PictureCollection and a singular Video object. Any hints? Also, is there a way to tell if the files are DRM Content?

Here is some sample code

```
void somefunction()
{

    MediaLibrary ML = new MediaLibrary();

    //returns a PictureCollection with [x] pictures in MediaLibrary
    PictureCollection PC = ML.Pictures; 

    //do something with IEnumerable object
    foreach (Picture obj in PC)
    {
        if (obj.Album.Name != "Sample Pictures")
            //do something
        else
            //ignore
    }

    //same thing for Audio Files...
    //returns a SongCollection with [x] songs in MediaLibrary
    SongCollection SC = ML.Songs;

    //what about video files??
}
```

My project is being being built to use Silverlight 4 and target WinPhone7.1

" C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll"

Comment: Please supply some code!

Comment: XNA is part of Windows Phone, not Windows Mobile and there is a *huge* difference.  If this is a Windows Phone question, update the tags and title.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access video library in Windows Phone 7. But it is possible 
in Windows Phone 8 by [`FileOpenPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx) in the `Windows.Storage` namespace.